# User Data Snooping by 3rd party libraries/SDK's. How to prevent that in android app?

Tags: android, security

Our android app uses some of the 3rd Party libraries and few SDKs. How can I ensure, that these 3rd party units are not snooping with my User data like User SMS, User call logs, User contacts.

```
                      All the above can be accessed be executing few lines of code. How to effectively prevent this.
```

Comment: You can deny those permissions in your manifest (simply by not including them), assuming you don't need them for your app's functions

Comment: I am using those permissions for my app as some of my functionalities are based on it

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ensure, that these 3rd party units are not snooping with my User data like User SMS, User call logs, User contacts.

Do not request permissions for those things.

> I am using those permissions for my app as some of my functionalities are based on it

Then remove those functionalities or remove the "3rd party units" that concern you.

For the subset of "3rd party units" that are open source, you are welcome to read through the source code to see what they do, then build your own copy of the library from the reviewed source code.